# Is it good practice to fake an inserter?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

We're taught to create function objects to use algorithms.

There are algorithms that call the `operator()`, like:

- for_each
- find_if
- remove_if
- max_element
- count_if

These function objects should typically inherit from `unary_function` or `binary_function`, to behave like a *function*, a *predicate*, etc.

But books don't generally demonstrate examples for creating `OutputIterators`:

e.g. to traverse the output of functions like
`std::set_intersection()`, I have to provide a destination container,
and *then* traverse the result:

```
std::vector<int> tmp_dest;

std::set_difference (
        src1.begin(), src1.end(), 
        src2.begin(), src2.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(tmp_dest));

std::for_each( tmp_dest.begin(), tmp_dest.end(), do_something );
int res = std::accumulate( tmp_dest.begin(), tmp_dest.end(), 0 );
```

but think that it would be more efficient sometimes to use the values of each algorithm, without storing them first, like:

```
std::set_difference (
        src1.begin(), src1.end(), 
        src2.begin(), src2.end(), 
        do_something );

Accumulator accumulate(0);  // inherits from std::insert_iterator ?
std::set_difference (
        src1.begin(), src1.end(), 
        src2.begin(), src2.end(), 
        accumulate );
```

- Should we generally create classes like this *Accumulator* ?
- What should its design look like?
- What should it inherit from ? 
  *Accumulator* could inherit from `insert_iterator`, but it is not really an iterator (eg it does not implement `operator++()` )

what are the widely accepted practices?

Comment: I'd say it is fine, but don't inherit from `insert_iterator`, it is *not* an insert iterator, it is an output iterator that consumes the data.

Comment: In the list of algorithms `std::for_each()` is different than the others: while the other algorithms use predicates, `std::for_each()` uses a consumer.

Comment: @Dietmar: actually, many times, `find_if` is used instead of `for_each` and you use the *predicate* as a *consumer*, but you also have the advantage of breaking the iteration early. So, really, they are all the same.

Comment: @GrimFandango: although the predicates can be used like consumers, there is actually no requirement that the same copy is called every time. If you assume the predicate is a consumer, make sure that the consumer part of the object has reference semantics. For `std::for_each()` there is a requirement that the function object is moved (if it is movable), i.e., this object won't be copied and can work directly as a consumer. I think there _is_ a difference between these function objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

class AccumulatorIterator
{
public:
    explicit AccumulatorIterator(int initial) : value(initial) {}

    AccumulatorIterator& operator = (int rhs) { value += rhs; return *this; }
    AccumulatorIterator& operator *() { return *this; }

    AccumulatorIterator& operator ++() { return *this; }
    operator int() const { return value; }
private:
    int value;
};

int main() {
    int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
    int second[] = {50,40,30,20,10};

    std::sort(std::begin(first), std::end(first));   //  5 10 15 20 25
    std::sort(std::begin(second), std::end(second)); // 10 20 30 40 50

    const int res = std::set_intersection (std::begin(first), std::end(first),
        std::begin(second), std::end(second), AccumulatorIterator(0));

    assert(res == 10 + 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This *cast operator* caught my attention. It's helpful, but isn't it a bit fragile? I mean, if the caller does not store the result to an `int`, it might not work as expected. Isn't a `int get_value() { return value; }` safer, because it's more explicit?

Comment: As the functor is taken by value, you can't use `get_value()` on the last argument of `std::set_intersection` (except if you use some sort of `shared_ptr<int>`). You may use `get_value()` in the `AccumulatorIterator` object returned by `std::set_intersection`. I mostly see `AccumulatorIterator` as a helper of a function. The class by itself seems strange.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an output iterator that calls your own function for every value received, use [Boost.Iterator's function_output_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a fundamental problem with this as long as it's clear to future maintainers how the codes works and what it's doing.

I would probably not inherit such an operation from any standard class (Other than giving it `output_iterator_tag`). Since we're dealing with templates we don't need to have a parent interface to deal with.

But keep in mind that your statement `(eg it does not implement operator++() )` doesn't seem to be correct: Whatever you pass in as the "output iterator" needs to meet the requirements of output iterators which include being copyable, dereference-to-assign, and incrementable. Whatever object type you pass in needs to meet these requirements.

Comment: What I meant was that *I might be giving the wrong impression to future maintainers* if I implement the operator++(), which is irrelevant from the caller's point of view (which is just a traversal function). Mark B, can you please explain, what is the reason for *not* having a parent interface? It works whether you inherit or not. I think it demonstrates an intent (ie to look like an iterator, a unary_function, etc). But is this kind of inheritance meant for other purposes?

Answer (score 3):

My take on this would be using Boost (also showing Boost Range algorithm versions of `set_difference`, although off-topic):

```
#include <set>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
#include <cassert>

void do_something(int) {}

int main()
{
    const std::set<int> 
         src1 { 1,2,3 }, 
         src2 { 1,9 };

    unsigned total = 0;

    boost::set_difference(src1, src2, 
                boost::make_function_output_iterator([&](int i) 
                { 
                    total += i*i; 
                }));

    assert(total == 13); // 2*2 + 3*3
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb69aa838ce0d7cd)**

Comment: neat! why don't things like that make it into the standard ?

Comment: @GrimFandango Not _yet_. Range proposals are being deliberated. You could add your voice at iso-cpp.org :/ I believe some sort of range concept should possibly get in c++1y - but it's hard to predict what 'flavour' (all competing ideas have their drawbacks, and the one that 'jells' the best with the rest of c++1y will probably win)

Answer (score 2):

The target of algorithms taking an output iterator is a sequence of values represented by an output iterator. They use iterators for two reasons:

1. It is quite likely that the result is stored somewhere else, i.e., an iterator is useful.
2. The protocol mandates that each position is written just once. This is more restictive than a function call interface, i.e., there is an additional guarantee.

For some algorithms both versions, one with a function call interface and one with an iterator interface, are provided. For example, that is the difference between `std::for_each()` and `std::copy()`.

In any case, if all you need is having a function called where an output iterator is needed, just have the other iterator operations be no-ops and call the function upon assignment to the result of `*it`: this creates a perfectly valud output iterator.